# In org-mode, is there a way to show the number of undone todo items in a subtree when collapsed?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

For example, suppose I have this document:

```
* category 1
** TODO item 1.1
** not a todo item
** DONE a done todo item
** TODO item 1.4
* category 2
** not a todo item
** not a todo item
* category 3
** DONE done item
* category 4
** TODO item 4.1
*** TODO subitem 4.1.1
*** TODO subitem 4.1.2
```

When collapsed, I'd like to see something like:

```
* category 1 (2)...
* category 2 (0)...
* category 3 (2)...
* category 4 (3)...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding [progress cookies](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html) to your ToDo items will reflect the number of done vs. total todo items.

Just add `[/]` at the end of the headline, and `C-c C-c` to update.

Example:

```
* category 1 [1/3]
** TODO item 1.1
** not a todo item
** DONE a done todo item
** TODO item 1.4
```

This works both for ToDo items or lists with checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks, TIL about statistics cookie. Too bad they don't work recursively, i.e. in category 4 it will show [0/1] instead of [0/3]. But hey, this is fantastic already.